# Save HashMap properties to a properties file, and load those properties back to the HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, properties-file

So I run into a casting problem with storing `HashMap` properties to a `Properties` file because the key of the `HashMap` is an object that cannot be cast to `java.lang.String` because properties must be `(String, String)` and my `HashMap` is `(Object, Long)`.

I just want to save the contents of the `HashMap` to a file so I can load those contents back into the `HashMap` the next time the program is ran.

I have gone through an excessive amount of worthless attempts to try to refill `HashMaps` with objects they contained before they were saved. I tried to think of an easy way to convert the object to a string which I can do, but since `Properties` and `HashMaps` are not indexed, I can not change those strings back to the object they need to be. How to achieve this?

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
    public File savedHashMaps = new File("SavedHashMaps.list");
// in my case, the object is 'Location' from an implemented API
public Map<Location, Long> map = new HashMap<Location, Long>();

public void saveMaps() {
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    try {
        if (!map.isEmpty()) {
            prop.load(new FileInputStream(savedHashMaps));
            prop.putAll(map);
            prop.store(new FileOutputStream(savedHashMaps), null);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void loadMaps() {
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    try {
        prop.load(new FileInputStream(savedHashMaps));
        if (!prop.isEmpty()) {
            map.putAll((Map)prop);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Properties file is not the correct way to save your data (`Map<Location, Long>`). You should come up with your own data file format that suits your data to be saved/retrieved.

Comment: You might be better off using the `ObjectInputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream` for this purpose rather than the Properties format unless you expect another program to read/write it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an `ObjectInput/OutputStream`

```
public File savedHashMaps = new File("SavedHashMaps.list");
public Map<Location, Long> map = new HashMap<Location, Long>();

public void saveMaps() {
    try {
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream (new FileOutputStream(savedHashMaps));
        oos.writeObject(map);
        oos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Catch exceptions
    }
}

public void loadMaps() {
    try {
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(savedHashMaps));
        Object readMap = ois.readObject();
        if(readMap != null && readMap instanceof HashMap) {
            map.putAll((HashMap) readMap);
        }
        ois.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Catch exceptions
    }
}
```

This is from memory, so sorry for errors, however this will save and reload all your Location, Long mappings. Also as a note, the Location class must implement `Serializable` (or have a super-class that implements it)(It's a marker interface (See java.dzone.com/articles/marker-interfaces-java) so you just add `implements Serializable`).

Comment: what would you do if the object isn't serializable?

Comment: You would have to implement your own method of saving/retrieving objects. Such as in XML. As to the implementation, that would depend on the contents of the file. It might be possible to implement one that uses the [Reflection API][http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html] so that you could save any object, however this won't work in applets.

Comment: I ended up making a serializedLocation class that just implemented serializable and handled the transitions to and from the standard Location object and the serialized Location object. I got it to work fine! thanks for your help!